# how to add image into <p> and used in UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

how to add image into `<p>` tag? In my html data multiple `<p>` tags. so how can i set different images to add and use in UIWebView.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you plz explain your question?

Answer (score 1):

To add image in HTML:

```
<p><img src="yourawesomeimage.png" alt="Awesome!" /></p>
```

To add HTML to UIWebView:

```
NSString* htmlContent = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><p><img src='image.jpg' /></p></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]];
NSString *htmlString = @"<p> <img src=\"sample.jpg\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\"/>";
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString 
                baseURL:url];
```

Comment: Small correction: Need to escape `"` in `htmlString`.

Comment: @Amar: yeah, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add html file to your project
2. Place your images next to .html file
3. Display image like this:
4. add viewcontroller to project
5. in viewcontroller add UiWebView And Link outlet to header file

Add This Code to view Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self redrawDesing];

NSURL *htmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"legal" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
[contentView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlFile]];
[contentView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
contentView.delegate=self;
[contentView setDelegate:self];
}
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

  return YES;
}
```

p.s replace "legal" with your html file name in this part 
 NSURL *htmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"legal" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];